# put_time() ignores conversion specifier 'z' for time zone offset

Tags: c++, windows, time, gnu

The following code shall print the time with the *time zone offset*, the lowercase format specifier `z` is passed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    time_t current_time = time(nullptr);
    tm* timeinfo = localtime(&current_time);
    cout << put_time(timeinfo, "%c %z") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

`g++ -o time time.cpp -Wall -pedantic`

The function [put_time()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) (C++) is described on [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com). The format specifiers are the ones from [strftime()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) (C). You can also read about them in the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards), currently page *396* in chapter *7.27.3.5*:

> ```
>   %z
> ```
>
> is replaced by the offset from UTC in the ISO 8601 format ‘‘−0430’’ (meaning 4
>       hours 30 minutes behind UTC, west of Greenwich), or by no characters if no time
>       zone is determinable. [tm_isdst]

This works well on Linux:

> Fri Jul 26 12:30:02 2019 +0200

But on Windows it's returning:

> 07/26/19 12:03:53 Mitteleuropäisches Sommerzeit

That's wrong, my code doesn't ask for the name of the timezone, but for the offset to UTC. I'm using on both platforms GCC as compiler.

**Question**
Am I doing something wrong here? Or is either GCC or Microsoft Windows violating the standard? I read some "rumors" about that it could be influenced through some settings on Windows.

Caluclating the offset by hand is rather treacherous. The best helper would be  [tm.gmt_offset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm), which is platform specific field. Therefore `gmt_offset` is not listed and only available on GNU based systems. I'm currently using a workaround based on [GetTimeZoneInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-gettimezoneinformation) and the fields `Bias` and `DaylightBias`, which is a platform specific Windows-API. I appreciate more secure suggestions.

Thank you for help and insights!

Environments:
GNU/Linux with GCC 9.1.0 (Archlinux)
Windows with GCC 8.3.0 (MSYS2)

Comment: How did you copy the source code to Windows? Did you rewrite the code and by mistake used upper-case `Z` instead? Upper-case `Z` would print the time zone name, or its abbreviation.

Comment: With Subversion. That was also my first assumption.

Comment: Okay, then it should be the same. :) Have you tried to change to upper-case `Z` and see what it prints on Windows? Perhaps there's a bug in the Windows implementation that it switches the meanings of upper- and lower-case?

Comment: Also did that, same result :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a [free, open-source (MIT license) 3rd party library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), it will give portable results.

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    zoned_seconds zt{current_zone(), floor<seconds>(system_clock::now())};
    cout << format("%c %z", zt) << '\n';
}
```

Though on Windows you will need to install [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), and on linux you'll need to link with `-lcurl`.  More detailed [installation instructions are available here](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).

This is a preview of the draft C++20 `<chrono>` library, though admittedly the syntax for the `format` statement is going to change slightly due to votes being taken just last week in Cologne.  C++20 will incorporate the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) (which is great news).

This library still uses `put_time` for the `%c` part of the format, but formats the `%z` part itself (and gives the offset in `[+/-]hhmm` form as desired).

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted your answer, because I hope it's fixing it by formatting itself, like you mentioned. While I read something about it, it wasn't aware that it formats itself. Despite we will not jump now ahead to C++20 or add more libraries in this case.